# How to create a field that shows results based on another field's selection?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm building a form for signing up to car services. I want to set up a choice field that shows value-based results depending on the user's selection in the first choice field. To be more specific; If first field choice (Car Manufacturer) is "Audi", second field (Car Model) shows only Audi models (because there are many of them, all Audi models have been assigned a value "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer a way to hide or disable choice field options at the moment, this is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/fDuf8Qku).

You can set up several Choice fields that only contain car models for the different car manufacturers. You can then use the 'Show When' logic and check to see what choice field option was selected. You can then have your different car model Choice fields show up when the car manufacturer option they relate to has been selected.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. I've already inserted all the models and assigned them values in my choice field, because I thought there was a way to write a custom value to make this possible. Considering there's about 60 choice fields for car models in my form, will I be able to display them in the correct position, because whenever I insert new choice field it appears in full-page width in the editor instead on the right side, where I want it to have?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured a workaround for this. I added fields to the left side of the form and set their visibility value to "Never" and then just added choice fields for car models to the right side. Now it all displays correctly. Thanks for your assistance!